# csv appears in weird letters even with right encoding

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

This is the code:

```
x = read.table('Dataset.csv',encoding = 'utf-8',sep =',',header = TRUE)
```

the column names appear like that: `Î.Î¹Î.`

In Python with `utf-8` it works correctly.

How to fix this?

Note:The letters are Greek.

Comment: Not an answer, but are sure the problem isn't with the R editor you are using, which is not displaying UTF-8 characters correctly?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I confirm that? Rstudio is the IDE

Comment: Your [mcve] should contain expected values (or better a sanitized part.of the `Dataset.csv` file)